# AttributeError by Allen NLP with pre trained Hugging face model

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, allennlp

I am using Allen NLP with the config file. I am trying to fine tune the model [MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-xnli-multilingual-nli-2mil7](https://huggingface.co/MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-xnli-multilingual-nli-2mil7) from Hugging Face. Unfortunately, I am getting the Error: `AttributeError: 'DebertaV2Model' object has no attribute 'pooler'`. Do you have any Idea what's wrong? Other Models do work. Very thankful for any help !

Here is the Config File:

```
local bert_model = "MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-xnli-multilingual-nli-2mil7";

{
    "dataset_reader" : {
        "type": "classification-tsv",
        "tokenizer": {
            "type": "pretrained_transformer",
            "model_name": bert_model,
        },
        "token_indexers": {
            "bert": {
                "type": "pretrained_transformer",
                "model_name": bert_model,
            }
        },
        "max_tokens": 100
    },
    "train_data_path": "data/sofa/train.tsv",
    "validation_data_path": "data/sofa/validation.tsv",
    "model": {
        "type": "simple_classifier",
        "embedder": {
            "token_embedders": {
                "bert": {
                    "type": "pretrained_transformer",
                    "model_name": bert_model
                }
            }
        },
        "encoder": {
            "type": "bert_pooler",
            "pretrained_model": bert_model,
            "requires_grad": true
        }
    },
    "data_loader": {
        "batch_size": 32,
        "shuffle": true
    },
    "trainer": {
        "optimizer": {
            "type": "huggingface_adamw",
            "lr": 1.0e-5
        },
        "num_epochs": 120
    }
}
```